# Paperclip, S3, Heroku: Missing Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

Long time viewer, first time asker. I've searched for this topic but don't believe I've found the answer.

I have a Post model that has an image. I'm using the Paperclip gem, saving to Amazon S3, and hosting on Heroku.

The file upload form works fine, because I can see that images are sent to my S3 bucket.

The issue is that, the images don't actually show in production.

Here's my model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :reviews

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "700x500#", small: "350x250>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

And here's my config/production.rb:

```
# Required for Paperclip / AWS
config.paperclip_defaults = {
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
}
```

And here's my show.html.haml file:

```
.clearfix
    .post_image_description
        = image_tag @post.image.url(:medium)
        .description= simple_format(@post.address)
        .description= simple_format(@post.description)
```

Shouldn't the `@post.image.url` be enough? What may I be missing to properly route to the image?

This is what I see when I pull `Heroku Logs`:

```
2015-06-23T15:38:26.181383+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/medium/missing.png"):
```

For reference, here's my repository for the project: https://github.com/lucasvocos/pitstop

Please let me know if there is anything else to provide in the question, too. As this is my first time asking. Thanks everyone.

Comment: did you set environment veriable?

Comment: also Image are uploading  your production bucket?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem that the upload was working but the display was showing a broken link. I checked the source for the link and it was not pointing to the url shown for the image on S3. I had to add the host name to my paperclip config

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_host_name => 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set heroku environment variable for s3 bucket variable:

```
heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME='Your Bucket Name'
heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='Your AWS ID'
heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='Your AWS Secrete Key'
```

Comment: Hi NaimRajib, I have done that already. The images do actually upload to my S3 bucket, the issue is viewing them.

Comment: @LucasVocos did you saw the heroku logs? did you run migration in heroku? Also please try to access the image field from heroku console. what it give as out put? if there set everything correctly there should not a issue. I think your code failed to save the prper url in the DB tables.

Comment: I ran the migration in Heroku, and got this:

Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.6820
      ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.5ms)  SELECT     "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit the missing.png in \public\images\medium.(make sure \public\images\medium\missing.png exist, then commit). This images is the default until you upload some valid image.

However, also is recommended to define the url in model, something like this:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { 
 medium: "700x500#",
 small: "350x250>" }, :url => '/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:basename.:extension'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The images uploaded are valid, and are getting pushed to my S3 bucket. The problem is, I don't think they are being routed correctly. I've followed all the steps [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) but I'm still getting a "missing image"

Comment: The error that you post is about missing.png. And this image is particulary in the repository not in S3 bucket. In the public directory.

Comment: For the other images I think you have to define an url in the model. I edit my answer to show.