# Rails Paperclip Heroku AWS DIsplay Image issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I set up paperclip in a rails app and this worked fine locally and on heroku, however the images uploaded in posts were only saved in heroku for a short space of time. I set up an AWS account and created a bucket, and followed through the documentation to link my rails app to AWS to display images uploaded with paperclip. I have attached code snippets below. The images seem to be uploaded to AWS fine, however when I create a post, it says my post has been created successfully, however the image does not display, it just displays as a broken link. When I click image properties, it hs the AWS S3 url and upon looking in heroku logs, there are no known issues. I do not know why the image is not displaying.

**config/environments/production.rb file:**

```html
# sets paperclip to upload images to Amazon S3
  # Variables directed to heroku via the command line for pw etc
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}
```

**post.rb model file:**

```html
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "600x", thumb: "100x" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

show.html.erb file:

```html
<div class="image">
          <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:medium) %>
        </div>
```

I have also set up heroku correctly using the following:

```
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=your_bucket_name
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
$ heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key
$ heroku config:set AWS_REGION=your_aws_region
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

As per Judd's answer for [Paperclip, S3, Heroku: Missing Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007617/paperclip-s3-heroku-missing-image), it was because I needed to state the s3_host_name in the paperclip default settings:

```html
# sets paperclip to upload images to Amazon S3
  # Variables directed to heroku via the command line for pw etc
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_host_name: 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
```